# Composite keys v surrogate keys for weak entities in MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb

Until now, I have been creating surrogate keys, to act as primary keys for each of my tables. I'm happy with this for the most part.

However, **for weak entities that are dependent upon other tables**, I have read that it is preferable to use a foreign key and one of the weak entity's attributes to create a composite key that acts as the primary key.

Is there any benefit to this method or can I continue using surrogate keys for all of my tables?

Comment: Please provide a concrete example.  Provide `CREATE TABLEs` for the competing approaches.  Then, keep in mind that different variations _may_ lead to different advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two-thirds of the tables I have ever written have a "natural" `PRIMARY KEY`.  Sometimes it is "composite".  There are even times where I put a surrogate after another column in the PK.

The reasons I use for deciding vary with the application and the size of the table:

- Often there is a 'natural' PK.
- Often `id AUTO_INCREMENT` is simply a waste of space, speed, etc.
- Sometimes there are queries that would benefit from fetching a "range" of rows -- Having the PK provide those rows consecutively can be a performance boost, hence tailoring the PK for that.
- If there are lots of secondary keys, it is *usually* better to have a shorter PK.  (Each secondary key has a copy of the PK column(s).)  This is *sometimes* a valid argument for adding a surrogate.
- Similarly, if several other tables need to link to this table, it is better to have a short PK.  (A surrogate is often shorter than a 'natural'.)
- `TEXT` and `BLOB` columns cannot be in a PK.

Here are 3 examples where a a composite natural PK is clearly better than a surrogate:

- [*many-to-many mapping table*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)
- [*EAV*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta)
- [*tags*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/lists)

Note: "weak entity" and "foreign key" are not considerations in *my* decision making.